# Passing variable between pages then image upload

Tags: php, mysql, image, variables

I have the need to upload some images onto my MySQL database. Ultimately what I want to achieve is a site that stores data on addresses, phones numbers etc. for a customer of ours. What I now want to do is associate an image with each site.

I have two tables in my database:

Table 1: 'Site Details'

1. Column 1: 'site_id'
2. Column 2: 'address'
3. Column 3: 'image'

Table 2: 'Topology'

1. Column 1: 'image_id'
2. Column 2: 'name'
3. Column 3: 'image'
4. Column 4: 'site_id'

My thinking here is that when someone clicks into a site, the URL will contain the variable in it, like so:

```
http://localhost:8888/testsite/site/14
```

When in that site, they can click a link called "Upload image". When they click that image, the site ID is passed along to the next page ($site_id having been captured via a mysql query further up the page):

```
<a href="../topology?site_id=<?php echo $site_id;?>">Upload Topology</a>
```

In the next page "topology" I have a form:

```
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process-upload-topology" method="post">
  <input name="image" type="file"> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

And then the page that processes the upload"

```
<?php
include("core/connect.php");

    //file properties
    $file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    if (!isset($file)){
      echo "<p>Please Select an Image</p>";
    } else {
      $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
      $image_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES['image']['name']);
      $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

      if ($image_size==FALSE) {
        echo "<p>Invalid image type</p>";

      } else {

      if(!$insert = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO topology (image_id, name, image) VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')")){
          echo ("<p>Error Uploading Image: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
        } else {
          $lastid = mysqli_insert_id();
          echo "<p>Your image has been uploaded successfully!</p>";

        }
      }
    }
?>
```

My aim ultimately is that each photo is associated with the site.

Comment: Is your issue with the code that uploads an image? Is that what does not work?

Comment: I read the post twice, but cannot find the question

Comment: @meda I think he's looking for reassurance he's on the right track, maybe better on codereview?

Comment: @andrew codereview is better for refactoring working code, however it seems OP has a good idea to solve the issue but did not implement it.